# Counter strike 1.6 - Add/Edit spawn points to existing maps

Tags: mods, counter-strike, counter-strike-condition-zero

I found [an article](https://www.reddit.com/r/counterstrike/comments/4vbhsp/16_editingadding_spawn_points_to_existing_maps/) tell how to do this

> You can do this with a tool called [bspedit](http://www.avamods.com/download.php?view.1)
>
> You can see the list of spawn point entities there, which you can change the x,y,z origin to move or you can copy paste an existing spawn and give it a new origin.

But is there easier way?

If there isn't, how can I add/edit spawn points to existing maps with bspedit.
For example, I has this mansion map, and when I open this map (cs_mansion.bsp) with bspedit, I got these code

```
{
"wad" "\sierra\half-life\valve\gfx.wad;\sierra\half-life\valve\halflife.wad;\sierra\half-life\valve\liquids.wad;\sierra\half-life\valve\decals.wad;\sierra\half-life\cstrike\cstrike.wad"
"WaveHeight" "1"
"skyname" "city"
"message" "Mansion"
"mapteams" "hgrunt;scientist"
"MaxRange" "4096"
"light" "0"
"sounds" "1"
"classname" "worldspawn"
}
{
"origin" "1336 392 64"
"angle" "270"
"classname" "info_player_start"
}
{
"origin" "136 -488 608"
"_light" "150 100 64 60"
"pitch" "-75"
"angle" "141"
"classname" "light_environment"
}
{
"origin" "-448 -584 232"
"angle" "180"
"classname" "info_player_deathmatch"
}
{
"style" "32"
"origin" "-128 -672 176"
"targetname" "lampa2"
"_light" "255 255 128 100"
"angle" "-2"
"classname" "light"
}
{
"style" "33"
"origin" "-128 160 176"
"targetname" "lampa4"
"_light" "255 255 128 200"
"angle" "-2"
"classname" "light"
}
{
"origin" "-528 160 176"
"style" "34"
"targetname" "lampa6"
"_light" "255 255 128 100"
"angle" "-2"
"classname" "light"
}
{
"style" "35"
"origin" "-528 -672 176"
"targetname" "lampa8"
"_light" "255 255 128 100"
"angle" "-2"
"classname" "light"
}
{
"style" "36"
"origin" "-136 -256 280"
"targetname" "lampa5"
"_light" "255 255 128 200"
"angle" "-2"
"classname" "light"
}
{
"style" "37"
"origin" "-128 160 280"
"targetname" "lampa3"
"_light" "255 255 128 100"
"angle" "-2"
"classname" "light"
}
{
"origin" "-128 -672 280"
"style" "38"
"targetname" "lampa1"
"_light" "255 255 128 200"
"angle" "-2"
"classname" "light"
}
{
"style" "39"
"origin" "-528 -640 280"
"targetname" "lampa11"
"_light" "255 255 128 100"
"angle" "-2"
"classname" "light"
}
{
"origin" "-520 -408 280"
"style" "40"
"targetname" "lampa10"
"_light" "255 255 128 200"
"angle" "-2"
"classname" "light"
}
{
"style" "41"
"origin" "-528 160 280"
"targetname" "lampa9"
"_light" "255 255 128 200"
"angle" "-2"
"classname" "light"
}
{
"model" "*1"
"rendercolor" "0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"classname" "func_wall"
}
{
"model" "*2"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "255"
"rendermode" "4"
"renderfx" "0"
"classname" "func_wall"
}
{
"model" "*3"
"classname" "func_ladder"
}
{
"model" "*4"
"rendercolor" "0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"buoyancy" "20"
"friction" "50"
"size" "3"
"classname" "func_pushable"
}
{
"model" "*5"
"classname" "func_wall"
}
{
"model" "*6"
"rendercolor" "0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"buoyancy" "20"
"friction" "50"
"size" "3"
"classname" "func_pushable"
}
{
"model" "*7"
"rendercolor" "0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"classname" "func_wall"
}
{
"origin" "1240 320 64"
"angle" "270"
"classname" "info_player_start"
}
{
"origin" "1336 264 64"
"angle" "270"
"classname" "info_player_start"
}
{
"origin" "1240 192 64"
"angle" "270"
"classname" "info_player_start"
}
{
"origin" "1336 136 64"
"angle" "270"
"classname" "info_player_start"
}
{
"origin" "1336 -1096 64"
"angle" "90"
"classname" "info_player_start"
}
{
"origin" "1336 -952 64"
"angle" "90"
"classname" "info_player_start"
}
{
"origin" "1240 -1024 64"
"angle" "90"
"classname" "info_player_start"
}
{
"origin" "1336 -824 64"
"angle" "90"
"classname" "info_player_start"
}
{
"origin" "1240 -904 64"
"angle" "90"
"classname" "info_player_start"
}
{
"origin" "-624 32 232"
"classname" "info_player_deathmatch"
}
{
"origin" "-632 -240 232"
"classname" "info_player_deathmatch"
}
{
"origin" "-632 -392 232"
"classname" "info_player_deathmatch"
}
{
"origin" "-392 32 232"
"angle" "135"
"classname" "info_player_deathmatch"
}
{
"origin" "-496 -464 232"
"angle" "90"
"classname" "info_player_deathmatch"
}
{
"origin" "-624 -584 232"
"angle" "315"
"classname" "info_player_deathmatch"
}
{
"origin" "-624 112 232"
"classname" "info_player_deathmatch"
}
{
"origin" "-536 200 232"
"angle" "315"
"classname" "info_player_deathmatch"
}
{
"origin" "-624 -672 232"
"classname" "info_player_deathmatch"
}
{
"origin" "-624 -176 200"
"gravity" "1"
"model" "models/scientist.mdl"
"angle" "327"
"classname" "hostage_entity"
}
{
"origin" "-624 -456 200"
"gravity" "1"
"model" "models/scientist.mdl"
"angle" "23"
"classname" "hostage_entity"
}
{
"model" "*8"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "255"
"rendermode" "4"
"renderfx" "0"
"classname" "func_wall"
}
{
"model" "*9"
"classname" "func_ladder"
}
{
"model" "*10"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "255"
"rendermode" "4"
"renderfx" "0"
"classname" "func_wall"
}
{
"model" "*11"
"classname" "func_ladder"
}
{
"origin" "1240 416 -64"
"_light" "255 255 128 200"
"angle" "180"
"classname" "light"
}
{
"origin" "-664 416 -64"
"_light" "255 255 128 200"
"classname" "light"
}
{
"origin" "-304 -272 64"
"gravity" "1"
"model" "models/scientist.mdl"
"angle" "168"
"classname" "hostage_entity"
}
{
"model" "*12"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"delay" "0"
"wait" "0"
"sounds" "8"
"lip" "0"
"health" "0"
"target" "kamera"
"speed" "5"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"targetname" "monitor"
"spawnflags" "33"
"classname" "func_button"
}
{
"origin" "1184 -560 176"
"deceleration" "500"
"acceleration" "500"
"speed" "0"
"wait" "15"
"targetname" "kamera"
"delay" "0"
"target" "aim"
"angle" "161"
"classname" "trigger_camera"
}
{
"origin" "944 -496 152"
"targetname" "aim"
"classname" "info_target"
}
{
"model" "*13"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"delay" "0"
"wait" "0"
"sounds" "14"
"lip" "0"
"health" "0"
"target" "lampa1"
"speed" "5"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"targetname" "knapp1"
"spawnflags" "33"
"classname" "func_button"
}
{
"model" "*14"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"delay" "0"
"wait" "0"
"sounds" "14"
"lip" "0"
"health" "0"
"target" "lampa2"
"speed" "5"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"targetname" "knapp2"
"spawnflags" "33"
"classname" "func_button"
}
{
"model" "*15"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"delay" "0"
"wait" "3"
"sounds" "14"
"lip" "0"
"health" "0"
"target" "lampa3"
"speed" "5"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"targetname" "knapp3"
"spawnflags" "33"
"classname" "func_button"
}
{
"model" "*16"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"delay" "0"
"wait" "3"
"sounds" "14"
"lip" "0"
"health" "0"
"target" "lampa4"
"speed" "5"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"targetname" "knapp4"
"spawnflags" "33"
"classname" "func_button"
}
{
"model" "*17"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"delay" "0"
"wait" "0"
"sounds" "14"
"lip" "0"
"health" "0"
"target" "lampa5"
"speed" "5"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"targetname" "knapp5"
"spawnflags" "33"
"classname" "func_button"
}
{
"model" "*18"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"delay" "0"
"wait" "0"
"sounds" "14"
"lip" "0"
"health" "0"
"target" "lampa6"
"speed" "5"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"targetname" "knapp6"
"spawnflags" "33"
"classname" "func_button"
}
{
"model" "*19"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"delay" "0"
"wait" "0"
"sounds" "14"
"lip" "0"
"health" "0"
"target" "lampa7"
"speed" "5"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"targetname" "knapp7"
"spawnflags" "33"
"classname" "func_button"
}
{
"model" "*20"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"delay" "0"
"wait" "0"
"sounds" "14"
"lip" "0"
"health" "0"
"target" "lampa8"
"speed" "5"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"targetname" "knapp8"
"spawnflags" "33"
"classname" "func_button"
}
{
"model" "*21"
"target" "lampa9"
"targetname" "knapp9"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"delay" "0"
"wait" "0"
"sounds" "14"
"lip" "0"
"health" "0"
"speed" "5"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"spawnflags" "33"
"classname" "func_button"
}
{
"model" "*22"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"delay" "0"
"wait" "0"
"sounds" "14"
"lip" "0"
"health" "0"
"target" "lampa10"
"speed" "5"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"targetname" "knapp10"
"spawnflags" "33"
"classname" "func_button"
}
{
"model" "*23"
"target" "lampa11"
"targetname" "knapp11"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"delay" "0"
"wait" "0"
"sounds" "14"
"lip" "0"
"health" "0"
"speed" "5"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"spawnflags" "33"
"classname" "func_button"
}
{
"model" "*24"
"target" "kamera2"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"delay" "0"
"wait" "0"
"sounds" "8"
"lip" "0"
"health" "0"
"speed" "5"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"targetname" "monitor2"
"spawnflags" "33"
"classname" "func_button"
}
{
"origin" "-320 -776 248"
"targetname" "kamera2"
"deceleration" "500"
"acceleration" "500"
"speed" "0"
"wait" "15"
"delay" "0"
"target" "aim2"
"angle" "90"
"classname" "trigger_camera"
}
{
"origin" "-304 -648 248"
"targetname" "aim2"
"classname" "info_target"
}
{
"model" "*25"
"classname" "func_wall"
}
{
"model" "*26"
"classname" "func_wall"
}
{
"model" "*27"
"classname" "func_wall"
}
{
"model" "*28"
"rendercolor" "0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"delay" "0"
"explosion" "0"
"material" "1"
"health" "2"
"classname" "func_breakable"
}
{
"model" "*29"
"health" "2"
"delay" "0"
"explosion" "0"
"material" "1"
"classname" "func_breakable"
}
{
"model" "*30"
"health" "2"
"delay" "0"
"explosion" "0"
"material" "1"
"classname" "func_breakable"
}
{
"model" "*31"
"origin" "0 -216 104"
"angles" "0 0 0"
"distance" "90"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"health" "0"
"delay" "0"
"dmg" "0"
"lip" "0"
"wait" "3"
"stopsnd" "0"
"movesnd" "10"
"speed" "100"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"classname" "func_door_rotating"
}
{
"model" "*32"
"origin" "-360 -768 104"
"angles" "0 0 0"
"distance" "90"
"unlocked_sentence" "0"
"locked_sentence" "0"
"unlocked_sound" "0"
"locked_sound" "0"
"health" "0"
"delay" "0"
"dmg" "0"
"lip" "0"
"wait" "4"
"stopsnd" "0"
"movesnd" "9"
"speed" "100"
"rendercolor" "0 0 0"
"renderamt" "0"
"rendermode" "0"
"renderfx" "0"
"classname" "func_door_rotating"
}
{
"style" "42"
"origin" "-488 -280 176"
"targetname" "lampa7"
"_light" "255 255 128 100"
"angle" "-2"
"classname" "light"
}
{
"origin" "-520 -232 280"
"style" "40"
"targetname" "lampa10"
"_light" "255 255 128 200"
"angle" "-2"
"classname" "light"
}
```

I see that there is "spawnflags" & "worldspawn" in this code, but I can't figure out where are the spawn points, which is for terrorist, which is for counter terrorist. Both "spawnflags" & "worldspawn", I don't see any location x,y,z.

Comment: The easiest way is to have the source code of that map and edit it in a map editor.

Comment: @dly, thank dly, I don't have the source of the map, so how can I use bpsedit, I tried to find how to use it, but I didn't find any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BSPedit or any other decompiler of that kind you can add/edit/remove spawn points as follows:

CT spawner:

```
{
"origin" "x y z"
"angle" "value"
"classname" "info_player_start"
}
```

T spawner:

```
{
"origin" "x y z"
"angle" "value"
"classname" "info_player_deathmatch"
}
```

`origin` defines the XYZ coords of the location and `angle`the rotation. The class name defines what team the spawner is for. Don't ask me why they named them that way.

Make sure you have enough space between your spawn points (at least 128 units on at least one axis) and no collision with any objects (even the ground!) or else they won't work.